# OpenCL, AMD Radeon, Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7 - How to get started?

Tags: windows-7, opencl, amd-processor

I'm a complete newbie with OpenCL, and I wanted to start learning how to code programs that will run on my video card (AMD Radeon 6970). I've installed AMD's app SDK, is this what I need to get started?

I tried building the sample solution they included, but I got:

> error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'd3dx10.h': No such file or directory  c:\users\...\simpledx10\SimpleDX10.hpp

I assume that this is because I have DX11 installed. I figured I would just make my own simple program to start off, but I couldn't figure out what all I needed to get it working after searching Stack Overflow and google.

Is there any useful guide for complete beginners to get OpenCL working in windows, using an AMD video card?

Comment: Have you installed the AMD APP SDK?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not really sure how it works, as the samples wouldn't compile.

Comment: Here, a lot of documentations :http://developer.amd.com/tools/hc/AMDAPPSDK/documentation/Pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is from the OpenCL book samples. If you don't mind using cmake to generate your projects build infrastructure then [this](https://code.google.com/p/opencl-book-samples/source/browse/trunk/cmake/FindOpenCL.cmake) CMakeLists should do just fine.

If you want a step-by-step tutorial on how to build and run a sample OpenCL application then I'll point you again at one of the auxiliary OpenCL book resources from [here](https://code.google.com/p/opencl-book-samples/wiki/Installation).

I'm also using cmake to build my OpenCL programs but the CMakeLists.txt file I'm using is pretty long and a bit twisted as it supports multiple compilers/platforms and it would only manage to confuse you.

Hope this helps you build your first OpenCL application. If not ask some more and I'll try to answer.

Comment: So I started following the step-by-step tutorial [here](https://code.google.com/p/opencl-book-samples/wiki/Installation). I got to the part that says "Click 'Configure'", and I picked Visual Studio 10 Win64.  
It gave me errors: [http://i.imgur.com/1fV1u.png](http://i.imgur.com/1fV1u.png)  
The tutorial says to install Stream SDK; I've installed the APP SDK (stream 1.2 instead of 1.1) - Is this the source of error? Otherwise, I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: @Syzothermy Did you create the environment variables: `OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIRS`, `OPENCL_LIBRARIES` AND `_OPENCL_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS`?  I feel like the APP SDK should have set those for you...

Comment: I went to Computer > Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables and didn't see any of those under System variables. I did see "AMDAPPSDKROOT" and "AMDAPPSDKSAMPLESROOT", so it did something, but not those three. Can I set those myself? What should they be set to?

Comment: Try something like this: http://pastebin.com/mSJ51Ag7. That's what I use to detect AMD APP SDK. Let me know if adding those variables helps.

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit slow to respond... how do I use this?

Comment: You put it in the CMakeLists.txt and use the resulting include and library paths.